# Regarding a mental disorder of finding pleasure and lose attraction

Tags: mental-illness

Say, a man is trying to find pleasure in doing something. he assumes he can have pleasure with playing, but just a while after start playing he feels definitely it can give him some pleasure. At that moment he stops playing and start finding for new form work/person/object/topic that can give him pleasure. It's not his/her fear to have the pleasure but it's like okay, anytime he can come back and have this any moment, a mean of it's in stock. But he never comes back until the feelings has been forgotten.

Is there a name of this type of disorder?

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE. I am curious as to why you ask about this. Is this a hypothetical situation or are you asking about a potential mental health disorder someone you know may be suffering from? Have you done any reading online to try and find an answer? If so, what is the closest you have found?

Comment: Thanks. I have seen some young kids of this generation are a days suffering in this. But my purpose is not to treat them or provide any solution. But to be aware what causes the disorder. The closest one I've found is ADD but the attention disorder is directly not that what these kids are suffering. It's also lack of seriousness and willingness too.

Comment: Add a bit detail, I'm an app developer. We specially develop free educational apps for kids and adolescent. In a recent survey, we found some of our user downloaded and found it useful but don't have any progress. That makes me curious.

Comment: There is something called the [scarcity heuristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scarcity_(social_psychology)), in which people place lower value on something that is readily available (not scarce), relative to something that isn't.  This for example leads to buying things and not necessarily using them (eg, impulse buying, hoarding, collections, fashion fads, etc).